# How to programmatically expand/bring up a search bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have a view controller with a `UISearchController` that, when tapped, will expand and bring up the keyboard. I want the user to press a button (separate from the search controller), when then brings up the search bar without actually tapping it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve is to make the searchBar become the first responder. You can do that with:

`searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()`

Comment: Or - `searchController.isActive = true`.

Comment: That doesn't bring up the keyboard and select the searchController's text field though